# simples pergunta: "porque eval() não funciona?"!

Tags: javascript, html, html5, script

Tenho um código simples a ser executado, eu nunca usei o eval, mas sei sua sintaxe:

```
var package = "edos.desktop";
eval(package + ".main()");
```

Porém não está funcionando no meu navegador...
Eu tentei usar algumas alternativas como `Function(package + ".main()")`, `setTimeout(package + ".main()");`,`setInterval(package + ".main()");`, mas por incrível que pareça, só o `setInterval()` funcionou, porém, ele ficou repetindo o código sempre que pode...

meu script com o código do main:

```
var edos = {};
edos.desktop = {
    main: function() {
        document.writeln("este é um app!");
    },
}
```

e eu preciso de uma solução, porque `eval()` não funciona, ou alguma alternativa para contornar o eval...

DETALHES DO DISPOSITIVO TESTADO:

```
Disposiivo: Moto G6 Play
Android: 8.0
Chrome Canary: 74
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o que vc está fazendo aí é chamar a função `c()` dentro de um objeto `a.b`. Melhor colocar o código completo na pergunta e explicar melhor o que pretende fazer.

Comment: Ok, mas era exatamente isso que eu queria mostrar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já considerou que o erro pode ser alguma outra coisa que não seja o eval?
"Eval não funciona" é improvável, não tem como um bug desse acontecer num navegador como o Chrome, mesmo no Canary. Faça o teste

```
const body = "document.body";
const firstChild = eval(body + '.firstElementChild');
console.log(firstChild);
```

Funciona, não funciona? Então o problema não é no eval.

> setInterval() funcionou, porém, ele ficou repetindo o código sempre
>   que pode

Quando você passa uma string para setInterval, ele roda o comando eval por trás das cortinas, outra prova de que não há nada de errado com o eval. A única diferença nesse caso, é que o setInterval vai esperar um pouco antes de executar o eval, ao invés de executa-lo imediatamente.

Seu problema não é o eval, revise seu código. Se por outro lado você insiste em usar algo setInterval para solucionar o problema, use `setTimeout`, que tem a mesma funcionalidade que o setInterval, mas só é executado uma vez.

Comment: Esse codigo que você disse acima retornou ```{ }```, isso é normal?

Comment: Ele retorna o primeiro elemento do `body`, se você rodar o código numa página vazia, o retorno será vazio.

Comment: o primeiro elemento é um ```<pre id="console">code <span>is</span></pre>```, e mesmo assim retornou ```{ }```

Comment: deve ser porque eu não uso ES6, mas sim o JavaScript...

Comment: EduApps, por favor, JavaScript é a implementação das regras definidas no ES6. Eu não tenho como te dizer qual o erro de um código que você não postou, mas não é problema no comando eval.

Comment: Cara, obrigado, o problema era que eu tinha pego o arquivo com a string "edos.desktop" por meio de um HttpRequest, e o eval foi chamado antes do HttpRequest ser terminado...